# Update a map field in all documents in Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and the library [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). I have two collections, `teams` and `users`. If a team's name is changed, the team's name must also be changed inside of the user's document.

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  team: TeamId;
}

export interface UserId extends User {
  id: string;
}

export interface Team {
  name: string;
  abbreviation?: string;
}

export interface TeamId extends Team {
  id: string;
}
```

Class:

```
const team: Team = {
  name: 'Yankees',
  abbreviation: 'YKS'
};

this.teamService.updateTeam('kbdf673bksbdj', team)
  .then(async res => {
    // The name has changed
    if ('Yankees' !== team.name) {
      await this.teamService.updateTeamNameInOthers('kbdf673bksbdj', team.name);
    }
  }, err => {
  });
```

From the service:

```
private teamsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Team>;
teams: Observable<TeamId[]>;

constructor(
  private afs: AngularFirestore) {
  this.teamsCollection = afs.collection<Team>('teams');

  this.teams = this.teamsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Team;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return {id, ...data};
    }))
  );
}

updateTeamNameInOthers(id: string, newName: string) {
  this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
    users.forEach(user => {
      if (user.team.id === id) {
        this.afs.collection('users').doc(user.id)
          .set({team: {name: newName}}, {merge: true});

        // I have tried
        // .update({team: {name: newName}});
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I have tried (transaction):

```
updateTeamNameInOthers(id: string, newName: string) {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      users.forEach(user => {
        if (user.team.id === id) {
          const userRef = this.afs.collection(config.collection_users).doc(user.id).ref;

          this.afs.firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {
            transaction.get(userRef).then(userDoc => {
              transaction.update(userRef, {team: {name: newname}}, {merge: true});
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

You can update any property of Team right now but, if you want to change all the properties of the team at the same time, the user's document is not updated. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it anyway.

My goal is, if the team's name changed, change the team's name in all user's document who belongs to that team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of ways you can do this. I don't recommend making these changes from the front end.

If your database structure is:

```
teams/team

users/user {
  team: { (not as a subcollection)
    id: string;
  }
}
```

Then you'll have to query all of the users like you are. The difference is that you'll want to use a [transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268241/angularfire2-transactions-and-batch-writes-in-firestore) to perform the operations all together or not at all if there is an error. Then you'll use the transaction to do the DB operations like this snipped from the linked answer `db.firestore.runTransaction(transaction =>` and `transaction.X` where X is your DB method.

*Alternatively*, I recommend doing this kind of functionality with [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). With this, you can listen to changes on the record without having to rely on the client side to make the changes. If the user makes a valid change, the Cloud Functions can do the transactional changes instead of performing the changes unreliably on the client side.

**After edit 1**
You should move the `this.afs.firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {` line above the `users.forEach(user => {` so all of the operations can share the same transaction. This way if there is an error with one of the updates, none of them will update.

**After chat**
The final solution was to use async/await with firestore.runTransaction, return a promise, update the records with transaction.update, resolving the promise after. A second part of the solution was to ensure you are not subscribed to the collection you are updating within the update!

```
// service method
getData(value: string): Promise<FancyType[]> {
  return this.afs.collection<FancyType>(
    'collection',
    ref => ref.where('value', '==', value)
  ).snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    take(1),
  ).toPromise();
}

// update method 1 transaction
const data: FancyType[] = await this.service.getData();

if (data) {
  await this.afs.firestore.runTransaction(t => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      data.forEach(d => {
        const dataRef = this.afs.collection('collection').doc(d.id).ref;
        transaction.update(dataRef, {...d, hello: 'World'});
      });
      res();
    });
  });
}

// alternate update method 2 batch
const data: FancyType[] = await this.service.getData();
const batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();

if (data) {
  data.forEach(d => {
    const dataRef = this.afs.collection('collection').doc(d.id).ref;
    batch.update(dataRef, {...d, hello: 'World'});
  });

  batch.commit()
    .then(res => {
      //on success
    }).catch(err => {
      //on error
    });
}
```

[Here is a reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for transactions and batches.

Comment: I saw that example but I didn't understand how to have the user's document reference, all of them in a batch, that example only do a reference to a specific document, but in my case, I don't know how many users belong to the team.

Comment: Inside of the runtransaction, you can do as many `transaction.X` as you like (there might be a max but I don't know it). The example only shows it doing one, but inside of the transaction you can call your `users.forEach(user => {` and do your set with the transaction since at that point you have your userId.

Comment: Te example only refers to one document reference, just one user's document, I have multiple documents to update. I'm very confused.

Comment: Call your usersService.getUsers. Then filter the results by the team id being the id you are looking for. Then start the transaction. Then loop over your filtered users and one by one add the user update or set to the transaction.
`transaction.set(this.afs.collection('users').doc(user.id)), <your data>, <merge>);` More info on transactions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: I receives an error, can you do an example and paste it in your answer please?

Comment: I'd rather you expand on your question with the second attempt, then I can update to assist accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188844/discussion-between-onelunch-man-and-rrgt19).

Comment: Hi, I have added a comment in chat.