# Firestore Update multitples fields in all documents where condition is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i am developing a chat application with firestore and angularfire2. where user structure is

```
   {
    displayName:"theusername***",
    email:"theuser***o@gmail.com",
    photoURL:"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-sXb0FiS_w7Q/xxdfd/xfQg5o8IRixaox1Ute1Q/photo.jpg",
    uid:"9zjJ8cH8PLSRjcW5rfTxI0xipcC3",
     }
```

and the chat structure below

```
     {
    receipient:"9zjJ8cH8PLSRjcW5rfTxI0xipcC3",
    uid:"GZI1AlbYObWJltzCVrlouRZLIU92",
   ***user_data_here*** ====> sender_data:{
                   displayName:"sendername***",
                   email:"sender***o@gmail.com",
                   photoURL:"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/IRixaox1Ute1Q/photo.jpg",
                   uid:"GZI1AlbYObWJltzCVrlouRZLIU92",
       },
     createdAt :1595285204356,
     receipient:"9zjJ8cH8PLSRjcW5rfTxI0xipcC3",
     uid:"GZI1AlbYObWJltzCVrlouRZLIU92",
     messages:{{content:"Hello Pal, Reply to this",
               createdAt :1595285245784,
               is_read:1,
               receipient:"GZI1AlbYObWJltzCVrlouRZLIU92",  //receiver
               uid":9zjJ8cH8PLSRjcW5rfTxI0xipcC3",         //sender
              },
              {content:"Hi Pal, this is reply!",
               createdAt :1595285245958,
               is_read:0,
               receipient:"9zjJ8cH8PLSRjcW5rfTxI0xipcC3", //receiver
               uid":GZI1AlbYObWJltzCVrlouRZLIU92",        //sender
              }
         }
     }
```

anytime the user profile is updated. i want to update all sender_data in chats if the uid matches with specified uid.  like the mysql equivaltent "UPDATE all chats where uid=$uid SET sender_data to $new_sender data. i have tried some transaction and batch writes and looked at some example but can't find where the condition chat's uid==$uid is considered.

this answer came close but couldnt do the trick
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814504/update-a-map-field-in-all-documents-in-firestore][1]

I also tried this  but suprisingly this doesn't work as well
Thanks

```
this.afs.collection('chats', ref => ref.where('uid' ,'==',uid))
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
        
          const data: Object = a.payload.doc.data();
          console.log(data);
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      // update here 
      =====> this.afs.doc(id).update({sender_data:data});
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
  );
```

Comment: If you've tried to implement this already, edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen this is what i tried recently.  thanks

Comment: You didn't check the call to update() for errors - something might have gone wrong, but you'd never know it.